# Can I give the default user that runs Perl scripts from cgi-bin different permisions?

Tags: permissions, xubuntu, perl, cgi

The default user that Perl scripts run from browsers is www-data.  My scripts need permission to read/write/delete files in other directories.  All these directories are created within the /home directory (all recursive, i.e. /home/Daniel/ftp/files) and these directories and files are created at run time by different users.

Is there a way to give www-data broader authority?  Should I change the default user that runs Perl scripts (again from browsers) even though that sounds dangerous?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should anyone come across this I found my answer.

The default user (for Perl/CGI commands) is located in /etc/apache2/envvars

I commented the line out

```
#export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
```

Replaced it with the user I wanted

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=franklin
```

then after saving the file I restarted the service

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I should note that even though I am sure it would have been the wrong thing to do, trying to make the default user 'root' produced an error.